# What are the underlying factors behind the varying intervals between suggested edit sessions

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Recently, I started reviewing suggested edits. After completing 20 edits, I receive thanks and come back later message. The odd thing I realized today is that the period behind "later" tends to vary.

I remember seeing, "come back in" {5, 6, 11} hours at different points.

What are the rules governing these varying intervals?

Comment: All time rules in SO are based on UTC time.

Comment: Thanks @AniMenon. I picked up that UTC was the time period in use, but I didn't realize that the reviewing suggested edits resets at midnight UTC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a UTC day.

The counter is reset when a new UTC day starts.

For example, if your last review was at 17:00 UTC, it will say "come back in 7 hours".
And if your last review was at 22:00 UTC, it will say "come back in 2 hours."

Comment: Aha. That explains it. Much simpler than I thought..